# If an image(s) is included as a background in css but not referenced in the html does it download?

Tags: css

I have a div with a background image set through an external CSS.
Using media queries, I am referencing different images based on the screen size.
But do all the images get downloaded regardless of screen size?

Comment: No, they get downloaded by their original size

Comment: If the CSS decides the screen is under 430px, only the image in that section of the media query will be called?

Comment: Open your browser's developer tools and look at the resources being downloaded.

Comment: @mHenderson exactly: https://jsfiddle.net/AleshaOleg/tu16728o

Comment: @j08691 I couldn't figure that out
Using Edge

Comment: So use Chrome or Firefox

Comment: @mHenderson In Edge, go to Developer Tools (F12) then click the Network tab. Then refresh the page to see all the resources that get downloaded.